# How to get the live video feed from my DJI Spark to my pc?(RTMP or RTP)

Tags: rtmp, dji-sdk

I want to get the live stream from DJI spark to my PC, because I want to run a deep learning model to do object detection in real time. Is there any ways to get the live stream by using RTMP or RTP servers. I found by using Tellopy module in python we can get the live feed from DJI tello.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean built-into the SDK, then the answer is no but you could decide the video stream yourself and package it up accordingly based on the needs of the server you wish to communicate with.

A few have done this work, the GO app, in order to support the various streaming sites has done it so it's known to be possible.  It might take some work though.

Best of luck!